# How to do callback in our component using react jest test cases

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks

How can we do callback on success and failue cases for below lines of code for test coverage using jest

```
const handleService = () => { 
 window.domain.service("1321",'',onSuccess, onFailure)
}

const onSuccess = () => {
....update state values
}
const onFailure = () => {
....update state values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

- Spy on `window.domain.service` to gain access to the calls it receives. This will allow you to access the parameters of those calls which will be `"1321",'',onSuccess, onFailure`
- Assign the function you wish to test to a variable
- Invoke the function to execute the code in it (this will get you the coverage)
- (Optional) assert that the callback functions behave correctly

Here is a snippet to help demonstrate

```js
it('should run', () => {
  // Some setup to create the function on the window, may not be needed if done elsewhere.
  // Could be good to do this in a beforeEach and clean up in afterEach to avoid contaminating the window object
  window.domain = {
    service: () => {},
  }

  // Spy on the window.domain.service method.
  // Provide a mock implementation if you don't want the real one to be called
  const serviceSpy = jest.spyOn(window.domain, 'service');

  executeYourCode();

  // capture the arguments to the call
  const [_arg1, _arg2, onSuccess, onFailure] = serviceSpy.mock.calls[0];

  // execute the callbacks
  onSuccess();
  onFailure();

});
```